# Powershell: How would I create multiple scripts that read and move files from the same directory to individual Folders?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to write a read and move function that can be placed in different scripts that will read and move from one shared folder (there's around  200k to 700k files in this directory).

So 3 or more script files looking into one source directory and moving them to a seperate individual directories

1. When I tried to point them all in same directory, I'll get errors some scripts as the file is no longer there, because it's been moved by another script.

Error: Get-ChildItem: Could not find item C:\temp\file1.txt

- While((Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Exclude *.copy

2. My script then tried to rename the extension therefore when another script looks into the directory it wouldn't pick up the file with the extension .copy

The issue I found was, if there's 500 thousand files, Get-Child runs through the whole list and gives the first one. Which will take quiet a while going through the loop.

After this, I still get the same error.

Both script has the same logic at this point,

Any ideas how I can just pull the first one available from the directory without going through the whole list and not touching files that other scripts are actioning. Mind you I know the while loop is also the bottle neck checking each time it's done.

```
While((Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Exclude *.copy | Measure-Object).count -ne 0)
{
    $MyFiles = Get-Child -Path ($Source) -Exclude *.copy|Select-object -expand name -First 1

    foreach($File in $MyFiles)
    {
        $FileName = "$SourcePath\$File"
        $FilenameCopy = "$File.Copy"

        Rename-Item -path $FileName -NewName $FileNameCopy

        Move-Item -Path :$SourcePath\$FileNameCopy" - Destination "$SeverFolder\$FileNameCopy"

        Rename-Item -path "$ServerFolder\$FileNameCopy" - NewName "$File"
    }
}
```

If the directory has over 500k of files, it's quiet slow as it's going through the whole list. Even with the -First 1

Erros occur when 2 or more instances of the same script runs will give a

Error: Get-ChildItem: Could not find item C:\temp\file1.txt

- While((Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Exclude *.copy

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're doing the Get-ChildItem work three times. Once to get the items, Once to iterate through them, last to check if any files still exist.  From your script it looks like you want to grab and move everything (with the -exclude only used due to filename changing to get the other 2 scripts to work).

You could simplify a bit with something like below

```
Do {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File | 
        ForEach-Object { #Act on each file as it passes in pipeline
            # Move & Keep same filename
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $ServerFolder
        }
} Until (
    !( # Stop if none found
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File |
        ForEach-Object { 
            if($_) { 
                $true
                break #Stop on first found with Get-ChildItem
            }
        }
    )
)
```